# api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search for every coordinate in python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, foursquare

## result dataframe

```
Municipality    Latitude    Longitude   Population2011
```

0   Agia Paraskevi  38.01263    23.82055    59,704
1   Agios Dimitrios 37.93667    23.73320    71,294
2   Alimos          37.91368    23.71506    41,720

```
search_query = 'Hospital'
categoryId = '4bf58dd8d48988d104941735'
```

## Define function to iterate in every row of dataframe and using its coordinates

## to fetch all "Hospital" venues for this coordinate

```
    def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):
    
    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):

            
        # create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit={}&locale={}&categoryId={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitudes, longitudes, VERSION, search_query, radius, LIMIT, locale, categoryId)

            
        # make the GET request
        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]
        
        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venues']['name'], 
            v['venues']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venues']['location']['lng']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    
    return(nearby_venues)
```

## call above function using as input Dataframe's "result" columns:

```
`all_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=result['Municipality'],
                                   latitudes=result['Latitude'],
                                   longitudes=result['Longitude']
                                  )`                                  )
```

Hello!
Please, I need your help!
I try to set as input each dataframe's coordinates to get Hospitals in each Municipality and create a new dataframe.

But It seems I can not correctly parse json (empty dictionary...)

Comment: I suggest that you edit your code format to make it more clear

Comment: Thank you! I try to clarify my code just now...

Answer (score 0):

## Hello!

## I slightly modified function and worked:

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, lat1, long1, radius=3000):

venues_list=[]
for name, lat, lng in zip(names, lat1, long1):
        
    # create the API request URL
    url1 = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit={}&locale={}&categoryId={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, lat, lng, VERSION, search_query, radius, LIMIT, locale, categoryId)

        
    # make the GET request
    results = requests.get(url1).json()["response"]["venues"]
    
    # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
    venues_list.append([(
        name, 
        lat, 
        lng, 
        v['name'], 
        v['location']['lat'], 
        v['location']['lng']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])

return(nearby_venues)
```